# Is it copy or reference when using var that = this?

Tags: javascript

when we use `var that = this`, is it copy or reference. It looks like `this` is a special object, so `that` should a reference. That means when `this` changes, `that` should also change? It is obviously not the case since `that` is remaining the same.

Anyone could clarify for this? why `var that = this` is a kind of "value copy"?

Comment: Within a given function's context, `this` cannot change.

Comment: @Paulpro's answer below is correct. In order for us to help you understand the specific behavior you're seeing, however, we would need to see the code producing that behavior.

Comment: I think you'll get a copy of the reference. So you can't use `that` to de reference `this`: `var that = this;that = null;` will not affect this. But since both that and this have a reference to the same object you can mutate this with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's copying a value called an object reference from `this` to the variable `that`. It's not that it's a special object, this is how *all* objects are referenced in JavaScript (including arrays and functions): What's stored in the variable (parameter, property, etc.) is a *reference* to the object elsewhere in memory, not a copy of the object.

Say you have this:

```
var a = {
    answer: 42
};
```

That creates a new object and stores the reference in `a`. In memory you have something similar to this:

```
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a:Ref3554−−−−−−>|  (object)  |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                | answer: 42 |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

There I've used Ref3554 to represent the reference value, but that's purely conceptual; you never see the actual value in code.

When you do this:

```
var b = a;  // Copies the value
```

it copies the value in `a` (the reference) to `b`:

```
a:Ref3554−−−+
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            +−−>|  (object)  |
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b:Ref3554−−−+   | answer: 42 |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

It's the same in your example, just with `this` instead of `a` and `that` instead of `b`.

> That means when `this` changes, `that` should also change?

`this` can't change within a scope. But `a` could, so let's continue with `a`. Suppose I do this:

```
a = {
    question: "Life, the Universe, and Everything!"
};
```

I've created a new object and assigned it to `a`. What happens to `b`?

Nothing whatsoever:

```
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a:Ref4269−−−−−−+|   (object)    |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                | question: ... |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b:Ref3554−−−−−−>|  (object)  |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                | answer: 42 |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Notice how `a` got a new reference (Ref4269). This has no effect whatsoever on `b`. `a` and `b` aren't linked in any way (nor are `this` and `that` in your example). They just happened to contain the same value for a  while, and then (as of the above), they didn't anymore, because one of them got changed.

But let's go back to when they were both pointing at the same thing:

```
var a = {
    answer: 42
};
var b = a;
```

```
a:Ref3554−−−+
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            +−−>|  (object)  |
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b:Ref3554−−−+   | answer: 42 |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Suppose I change the **state** of the object that both `a` and `b` refer to?

```
a.answer = 27;
```

What happens to `b`? Well, `b` is unchanged, but the object it's pointing to is the same object that `a` points to, and that object's state was just changed, so naturally you see that new state regardless of which variable you use to get access to the object:

```
a:Ref3554−−−+
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            +−−>|  (object)  |
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b:Ref3554−−−+   | answer: 27 |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: the problem is: when "this" gets changed , for example, inside an inner function, why "that" remains unchanged?

Comment: @AdamLee - Because there's no connection whatsoever between `this` and `that` (or `a` and `b` in my example). None whatsoever. It's just that for a while, they both have the same value. Then later, they don't. (I just updated the answer to try to show that.) It's exactly like if `a` has 1 in it, and you do `b = a` so now `b` has 1 in it as well, and later you do `a = 5`. No change to `b`. There's no ongoing link.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the case. `that` references the exact same object as `this`:

```js
new function ( ) {
    var that = this;
    this.x = 5;
    console.log( that );
}
```

If you're wondering why `this` can be different inside an inner function. That's basically just shadowing. Every regular function call in JavaScript has its own `this`, so any `this` of an outer scope is inaccessible. This example:

```js
new function ( ) {
    var that = this;

    console.log( this === that ); // true

    new function ( ) {
        console.log( this === that ); // false
    };

    console.log( this === that ); // true
}
```

is similar to this:

```js
var a = { };
var b = a;
 
console.log( a === b ); // true
(function ( ) {
    var a = { };
    console.log( a === b ); // false
})();
 
console.log( a === b ); // true
```

That's not the case with arrow functions though:

```js
new function ( ) {
    var that = this;

    console.log( this === that ); // true

    (_ => console.log( this === that ))(); // true, arrow function has the same this as outside

    console.log( this === that ); // true
}
```

Comment: the problem is: when "this" gets changed , for example, inside an inner function, why that remains unchanged?